# Output error resulting from logic error when determining percentage based on incremental while loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, logic

I have created a simple class which calculates the win/loss percentage and returns the amount of necessary consecutive wins to obtain the desired win/loss percentage of the given input from the user, based on the given values of wins, loss, and desired win/loss. However, whilst running the program, I notice the output gives an exceedingly large number in the place of what should be a relatively small number (the number of wins needed). I am not certain what error I have made that created this, but I'm certain it's relative to the while loop located in my `howManyToWinLoss()` method, or perhaps some error I've made in the tester class's output. At any rate, they are both located below, and I appreciate the assistance:

```
public class WinLossCalculator
{
    private int win;
    private int loss;
    private int totalGames;
    private double desiredWinLoss;
    private double winLoss;
    private int gamesToDWL;

    public WinLossCalculator(int w, int l, double dwl)
    {
        win = w;
        loss = l;
        totalGames = w + l;
        desiredWinLoss = dwl;
    }

    public double winPercent()
    {
        return winLoss = (double)win/(double)totalGames;
    }

    public double lossPercent()
    {
        return (double)loss/(double)totalGames;
    }

    public int howManyToWinloss()
    {
        int x = 0;
        while(winLoss < desiredWinLoss)
        {
            winLoss = (win+x)/(win+x+loss);
            if(winLoss < desiredWinLoss)
            {
                x++;
            }
        }
        return gamesToDWL = x;
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.*;
public class WinLossTester
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the amount of matches you've won: ");
        int wins = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEnter the amount of matches you've lost: ");
        int losses = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEnter your desired match win percentage (eg. 75.4): ");
        double desiredWLP = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println();

        WinLossCalculator one = new WinLossCalculator(wins, losses, (desiredWLP / 100));

        one.winPercent();
        one.howManyToWinloss();

        System.out.printf("Win percentage: %6.1f", (one.winPercent()*100));
        System.out.print("%");
        System.out.printf("\nLoss percentage: %5.1f", (one.lossPercent()*100));
        System.out.print("%");
        System.out.println("\nVictories required to reach desired W/L percent (without loss): " + one.howManyToWinloss());
    }
}
```

Additionally--I feel as though my tester class's output section is a little ugly, might anyone have any suggestions concerning formatting or cleaning up the code in the output section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently it has to do with me not casting the first line in my for loop to double like this `winLoss = (double)(win+x)/(double)(win+x+loss);` I don't know why that broke it, but, that's why it was broken.